# Nest.js: Pass the provider to the decorator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-decorator

I create a custom decorator for spawning

It is necessary to pass the mongoose model to the decorator

Provider

```
export const dbModelsProviders: FactoryProvider[] = [
{
    provide: Db.USER_MODEL,
    useFactory: (connection: Connection): Model<IUser> => connection.model('User', userSchema),
    inject: [Db.DATABASE_CONNECTION]
}
];
```

It is necessary to pass this provider through the parameter or in any other way to another decorator

```
@Crud({
name: 'Test',
defaultDto: TestDto,
defaultResponseDto: TestDto,
model: <--
})
@Controller()
export class AppController {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
@Crud({
   name: 'Test',
   defaultDto: TestDto,
   defaultResponseDto: TestDto,
   model: mongoose.model('User')
}) 
@Controller()
export class AppController {}
```

hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tell me pls, what module is this variable?

Comment: Edited for clarity sry. Just import { Model } from 'mongoose';